# Организация сервера для приложения

Tags: android, сервер, servlet

Добрый день!
Очень интересует один вопрос, перерыл кучу инфы, но должного ответа не получил.
Есть тестовое приложение под Android, оно должно получать картинки с сервера, собственно сам вопрос:
Как организовать сервер? Прописывал сервер на сокетах на Java, на тестах все отлично работает с localhost, но я не могу понять куда мне обратиться в какой хостинг для того, чтобы этот мой написанный сервер туда поставить? Что за механизм нужен, чтобы сам сервер работал бесконечно при технических сбоях? Прошу более развернутый ответ с ссылками и ресурсами.

Answer (score 1):

Тебе нужен хостер, который предоставляет услугу VPS.
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/VPS

Comment: А дальше? Я гружу туда класс и что?

Comment: VPS это обычный комп тока гдето в датацентре. Делай там тоже самое, что делал на локалхосте и все.